# Are there situations where we can use either "say" or "tell", but not both, in a sentence? Consider the following examples:

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar

**Are these examples grammatically correct?**

**1**:

> I want to tell you something./ I want to tell you that _______.
>
> I want to say something to you./ I want to say to you that _______.

**2**:

> You just told five people we met today that they're special.
>
> You just said to five people we met today that they're special.

Answer (score 0):

We say "*Tell* the truth," or 'a lie' or 'a fortune' or 'the future' - we *say* our prayers", *say* we're sorry, *say* so, and "Say What?"